# "specialize" a base object to become a derived object?

Tags: c++, c++11, object, inheritance, syntax

Is it possible to "specialize" a base object to become a derived object?

For example:

```
class base{...
  base(...) : ... {}//both have their own constructors
  virtual void foo(){}
};

class derived : public base{...
  void foo() override; //actual function in cpp
...};

int main(){
  base x;
  //is it possible to do something to x so
  x.foo(); // will call derived::foo()
}
```

Comment: Yes, create a constructor `derived(const base &)`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That allows a new `derived` to be constructed from `x`, but doesn't change `x` to become that new `derived` object. I think the OP is after that last part. But that's not possible.

Comment: How would you use it? say here with `x`? @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: The function `foo` in `base` needs to be declared `virtual` for polymorphism to work. In your example instead of `base x;` declare the variable as `derived x;` (with known most derived type the function oesn't need to be virtual). That's it.

Comment: @kuhaku: `derived(x).foo();`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf but then you don't have a question to ask. "How do you make a derived become a derived?" It already is.

Comment: @n.m:  right, this isn't a question. voting to close.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth but that won't change `x` permanently to become `derived` right?

Comment: It's not a meaningful question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well that's your opinion.

Comment: @kuhaku - No, because that's not possible (or meaningful).  What's the specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question makes perfect sense. The answer happens to be "no, you can't do that". There are languages that allow such things, C++ is just not one of them.

Comment: @kuhaku: that's a fact, not an opinion. you need to be a bit more humble. you, as the one who asks, is the one who knows less.

Comment: To answer that it's not possible is also an answer, that doesn't make a question invalid.

Comment: In languages where it's possible, it's used extremely rarely, but it does get used. I've used tricks like that in Delphi. Based on that, I agree with @n.m. that the question is meaningful and the answer is "you can't". However, even in those other languages, the answer should include a "you probably shouldn't" -- it makes the code a right mess to follow. What's the reason for wanting this? Perhaps you can get a decent answer of something else that is possible in C++.

Comment: @hvd I've heard about an experimental language which lets you evolve an object from base to derived and devolve it back in the end. It's not a trick, it's the dominant mode of using objects there. Don't remember the name of the language though.

Comment: If it matters now, what I'm trying to do is hold a list of `base` and iterate over it, activating the overridden `foo` of each `derived#i` class.

Comment: @kuhaku - The answer below is the answer to your literal question.  I suspect that this isn't going to help you though - why are you in a position where you want/need to be able to call derived members on a base instance?  There is probably a better overall approach here.

Comment: @kuhaku Do you mean you have `derived1`, `derived2`, `derived3`, etc.? How would you be able to tell from your `base` instance what the type should be? It seems like you should be dealing with a list of `shared_ptr<Base *>` instead, not a list of `Base`, that way you'd avoid the whole problem.

Comment: Yeah there are several `derived`, there's a data member in `base` that will indicate which derived it should be. So a pointer of `base` can be "specialized" to be `derived`? @hvd

Comment: @kuhaku Yes, that's standard functionality, if you have a `base *`, you can assign it a pointer to `derived1`, and virtual methods called through that pointer will resolve to the overridden method in `derived1`.

Comment: Great this will also allow `base` to be an abstract class with `virtual foo()=0`, thanks @hvd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way in standard C++ to change the type of any existing object. The only thing you can do if you really need a different type is construct new objects, or resort to non-portable hacks, as the other two answers show. Luckily, in your case, you don't need to change any object's type.

Based on the comments, here's a simple program of how you can keep `derived1` as `derived1`, how you can make sure it's never converted to a real `base` object, so virtual methods work as expected without being forced to attempt to convert `base` back into the derived class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

struct base {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "base::print()" << std::endl; }
};

struct derived1 : base {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "derived1::print()" << std::endl; }
};

struct derived2 : base {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "derived2::print()" << std::endl; }
};

struct derived3 : base {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "derived3::print()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  std::list<std::shared_ptr<base>> list;
  list.push_back(std::make_shared<base>());
  list.push_back(std::make_shared<derived1>());
  list.push_back(std::make_shared<derived2>());
  list.push_back(std::make_shared<derived3>());
  for (auto item : list)
    item->print();
}
```

Output:

```
base::print()
derived1::print()
derived2::print()
derived3::print()
```

Note that no `type` member inside `base` is necessary for `item->print()` to call the correct method, the compiler already handles this for you.

Comment: This is perfect. Is it possible to do this without `make_shared`? Probably to make a temporary object of type `derived#i` and push it to the list?

Comment: @kuhaku A `list<base>` only allows storing `base` objects, not any derived object. You could technically avoid `make_shared` and use `list<base *>`, and then write `list.push_back(new derived1());`, but that means you allocate memory that you never free, it gives you a memory leak. `shared_ptr`/`make_shared` is the simplest way of making it just work.

Comment: While this apparently answers the Real Question™, it's **not an answer** to the question as posed. It should probably be *a comment*. Flagged as such.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If it makes you happy, I'll include "You can't, but..." at the start of this answer, but it seems fairly pointless to me.

Comment: @hvd: The thing that makes the whole answer a comment, is that "how you can keep derived1 as derived1" is not in the posted question at all, not even implied.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But the "You can't" would be a complete and correct answer to the literal question that's asked, so if I include that, I do definitely unambiguously answer the question, right?

Comment: @hvd: Yes, I agree. You could link to my answer for info about the non-standard (im-) practical technique and how dangerous it is. ;-)

Comment: But this is not an answer to the original question, which was about mutating objects!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Oh FFS. I dealt with that already. You can't. "You can't" is a complete and correct answer to the original question. I edited my answer to include that already.

Comment: No "he can" if he use delegation to implement specialization.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That still doesn't make a base object become a derived object, so "you can't" is still the correct answer. If you'll notice, the other two answers *also* say you can't, and proceed to post workarounds, in R Sahu's case by constructing a new object rather than modifying an existing one, in Alf's case by not limiting himself to standard C++. If you have a better workaround than what I posted in the existing answers, then post it yourself. Otherwise, please go bother someone else. I'm done here unless you have something constructive to add.

Comment: Of course it does. A derived object is one that behave like it is intended to, so delegation answers the question well. It is a mistake to believe that the type system is the ultimate solution, deriving a class does not means use inheritance.

Comment: I think it's worse to tell me which answer to accept. Not that R Sahu's is wrong, but this one is better for my needs.

Comment: BTW what is it called? To make a `base` pointer become a `derived` pointer?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  //is it possible to do something to x so
>  x.foo(); // will call derived::foo()
> ```

No, you cannot, at least not in a portable and standards compliant way.

However, you can create a `derived` from `x` and then use it.

First, add a constructor in `derived` that takes a `base` as an argument.

```
class derived : public base{
  derived(base const& b) { ... }
  void foo() override; //actual function in cpp
...}
```

Now use it:

```
derived(x).foo();
```

Comment: It is possible using delegation and not inheritance.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, elaborate, please.

Comment: `class B { Imp *i; foo() { i->foo(); }`, now put what you want, either change dynamically the `i` pointer to something implementing `foo()` (`Imp` should be a type with a `foo` method). This is the way to implement dynamic subtyping, implement your own *virtual* mechanism...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, Thanks for the details. Now that you have explained it a bit more, I realize that I have used it in the past.

Answer (score 2):

### The question and simplistic answer.

Given code:

```
class base{...
  base(...) : ... {}//both have their own constructors
  virtual void foo(){}
};

class derived : public base{...
  void foo() override; //actual function in cpp
...};

int main(){
  base x;
  //is it possible to do something to x so
  x.foo(); // will call derived::foo()
}
```

The question is then

> ” Is it possible to "specialize" a base object to become a derived object?

E.g. change the dynamic type of `x` in the above code.

In portable standard C++, no.

### Why it's not generally meaningful.

Class `derived` will generally have additional data members and possibly a different class invariant compared to `base`. Access of those missing data members in a `base` instance, as if that instance were a `derived`, will generally yield Undefined Behavior. Relying on the `derived` class invariant for a `base` instance can likewise wreak havoc.

### How it can be non-portably done in special cases.

As far as I know every extant C++ implementation implements the virtual function mechanism by storing a **vtable pointer** (plus possibly more info) in each object. The **vtable** is a class-specific single table of pointers to virtual function implementations. By changing an object's vtable pointer one can force it into acting as if it is of some derived class, e.g.:

Example for 64-bit Windows program

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual auto foo() -> int { return 111; }
    Base() {}
};

struct Derived
    : public Base
{
public:
    auto foo() -> int override { return 222; }
};

namespace cast {
    template< class Type >
    auto temp_ref( Type&& o ) -> Type& { return o; }
}

auto test( Base& o ) -> int { return o.foo(); }

#include <iostream>
auto main() -> int
{
    Base x;

    //is it possible to do something to x so
    auto const r1 = x.foo(); // will call derived base::foo()?

    // Yes, non-portably. Here for MingW g++ 64-bit.
    reinterpret_cast<void*&>( x ) =
        reinterpret_cast<void*&>( cast::temp_ref( Derived() ) );
    auto const r2 = x.foo();    // May still call base::foo()
    auto const r3 = test( x );  // More likely to call derived::foo()

    using namespace std;
    cout << r1 << " -> " << r2 << " -> " << r3 << endl;
}
```

With 64-bit MingW running in Windows I get the following result:

```
111 -> 111 -> 222
```

Formally this is very much Undefined Behavior, and since the compiler at points in the source code can assume that it knows the vtable pointer of a particular object, it can mysteriously Not Work™ in some cases. The second `111` in the above result is an example. I.e., this is *unreliable*, and while I worked as a consultant I became aware of one project where this technique was used, although in Visual Basic, with horrendous problems as a result.

Also it's non-portable because vtable pointers can be of different sizes such as 32-bit versus 64-bit, and compilers need not store them at the same places. To do this with more assured effects a standard binary layout is needed. For example, Microsoft's COM technology provides such a binary layout standard.